# Attempting to pass Flow variable to Apex to use in HTTP request & create PDF

Tags: httprequest, contentdocumentlink, blob.topdf

I think I'm quite over my head in this class. I'm trying to do about three different things that are brand new to me. In short, I'm trying to do this :

- Pass a variable to an Apex class from a Flow (after calling the class in a Flow)
- Use that variable in an HTTP callout in the Apex class
- Use getBodyAsBlob to turn the HTTPResponse of the callout into a PDF file
- Save the new PDF file in the parent record of the current record running the Flow

So far my research has yielded this. I'm currently getting an error right from the first @InvocableMethod line.

Any advice you can give would be so appreciated. I know the code needs some more. I've been pulling my hair out on it.

******UPDATED CURRENT CODE (creates file but 'not supported file type') :**

```
public class Lookup_File_Creation {
    public class Request {
        @InvocableVariable (required=true) public String paynet_id; 
        @InvocableVariable (required=true) public String linkedEntityId; 
        @InvocableVariable (required=true) public String var_filename; 
    }
    class Wrapper {
        Request req;
        ContentVersion cv;
        Id contentDocumentId;
        ContentDocumentLink cdl;
        Wrapper(Request request) {
            req = request;
        }
    }
    @InvocableMethod(label='LOOKUP FILE CREATE' description='API FILE CREATION')
    public static void doGetClient(Request[] requests) {
        Wrapper[] wrappers = wrapRequests(requests);
        doCallouts(wrappers);
        createContentVersions(wrappers);
        getContentDocumentIds(wrappers);
        createDocumentLinks(wrappers);
    }
    static Wrapper[] wrapRequests(Request[] requests) {
        Wrapper[] results = new Wrapper[0];
        for(Request request: requests) {
            results.add(new Wrapper(Request));
        }
        return results;
    }
    static void doCallouts(Wrapper[] wrappers) {
        Http http = new http();  
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        String endpoint = 'callout:GovernmentSvcNamed/credit/commercial/GetReport';  
        req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Accept','application/pdf');
        for(Wrapper item: wrappers) {
            req.setBody(
                JSON.serialize(
                    new Map<String, Object> {
                        'paynet_id' => item.req.paynet_id
                    }
                )
            );
            String fileName; 
            HttpResponse res = http.send(req);                
            item.cv = new ContentVersion(
                VersionData = res.getBodyAsBlob(),
                Title = item.req.var_filename,                                       
                PathOnClient = '/' + item.req.var_filename
                
            );
        }
    }
    static void createContentVersions(Wrapper[] wrappers) {
        ContentVersion[] versions = new ContentVersion[0];
        for(Wrapper item: wrappers) {
            versions.add(item.cv);
        }
        insert versions;
    }
    static void getContentDocumentIds(Wrapper[] wrappers) {
        Id[] versionIds = new Id[0];
        for(Wrapper item: wrappers) {
            versionIds.add(item.cv.Id);
        }
        Map<Id, ContentVersion> versionsById = new Map<Id, ContentVersion>([
            SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id = :versionIds
        ]);
        for(Wrapper item: wrappers) {
            item.contentDocumentId = versionsById.get(item.cv.Id).ContentDocumentId;
        }
    }
    static void createDocumentLinks(Wrapper[] wrappers) {
        ContentDocumentLink[] recordLinks = new ContentDocumentLink[0];
        for(Wrapper item: wrappers) {
            ContentDocumentLink link = new ContentDocumentLink(
                ContentDocumentId = item.contentDocumentId,
                linkedEntityId = item.req.linkedEntityId, // RecordID of Relationship 
                ShareType = 'V'//User can view file
            );
            recordLinks.add(link);
            item.cdl = link;
        }
        insert recordLinks;
    }
    
}
```

**Here is what is shown when the file is opened in a text editor :**

```
{
  "pdf" : {
    "content_type" : "application/pdf",
    "filename" : "MAIN DOC - 132343097.pdf",
    "filesize" : "15109",
    "file" : "JVBERi0..............RU9GCg=="
  },
  "status" : "0"
}
```

The "file" section is much longer, full of the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, don't copy from Office products. It screws up your code with "Smart Quotes", which don't compile in Apex.

Secondly, your InvocableMethod annotation has an error because you forgot to put a function next to it:

```
@InvocableMethod(label='Get Client Info' description='Gets the client info')
public static void doGetClient(Request[] requests) {
  // ... code will go here
}
```

Third, given the nature of your code, I'd recommend a wrapper along with the other objects.

```
public class Request {
  @InvocableVariable (required=true) public String client_id;
  @InvocableVariable (required=true) public String linkedEntityId;
}
class Wrapper {
  Request req;
  ContentVersion cv;
  Id contentDocumentId;
  ContentDocumentLink cdl;
  Wrapper(Request request) {
    req = request;
  }
}
```

Now, notice we're receiving a list of inputs. This happens because of [flow bulkification](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_concepts_bulkification.htm&language=en_US&type=5). Even if you plan on never doing this, you never know when you might need it, so you may as well write it correctly the first time.

Here's our new design:

```
@InvocableMethod(label='Get Client Info' description='Gets the client info')
public static void doGetClient(Request[] requests) {
  Wrapper[] wrappers = wrapRequests(requests);
  doCallouts(wrappers);
  createContentVersions(wrappers);
  getContentDocumentIds(wrappers);
  createDocumentLinks(wrappers);
}
```

Remember, you can't callout after a DML, so this design ensures you're doing it correctly.

Let's look at these methods:

```
static Wrapper[] wrapRequests(Request[] requests) {
  Wrapper[] results = new Wrapper[0];
  for(Request request: requests) {
    results.add(new Wrapper(Request));
  }
  return results;
}
static void doCallouts(Wrapper[] wrappers) {
  Http http = new http();
  HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
  req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
  req.setMethod('POST');
  req.setHeader('Accept','application/pdf');
  for(Wrapper item: wrappers) {
    req.setBody(
      JSON.serialize(
        new Map<String, Object> {
          'client_id' => item.req.var_from_FLOW
        }));
    HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
    item.cv = new ContentVersion(
      VersionData = res.getBodyAsBlob(),
      Title = fileName,
      PathOnClient = fileName // And anything else I missed
    );
  }
}
static void createContentVersions(Wrapper[] wrappers) {
  ContentVersion[] versions = new ContentVersion[0];
  for(Wrapper item: wrappers) {
    versions.add(item.cv);
  }
  insert versions;
}
static void getContentDocumentIds(Wrapper[] wrappers) {
  Id[] versionIds = new Id[0];
  for(Wrapper item: wrappers) {
    versionIds.add(item.cv.Id);
  }
  Map<Id, ContentVersion> versionsById = new Map<Id, ContentVersion>([
    SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id = :versionIds
  ]);
  for(Wrapper item: wrappers) {
    item.contentDocumentId = versionsById.get(item.cv.Id).ContentDocumentId;
  }
}
static void createDocumentLinks(Wrapper[] wrappers) {
  ContentDocumentLink[] recordLinks = new ContentDocumentLink[0];
  for(Wrapper item: wrappers) {
    ContentDocumentLink link = new ContentDocumentLink(
      ContentDocumentId = item.contentDocumentId,
      linkedEntityId = item.req.var_from_FLOW2,
      ShareType = 'V'
    );
    recordLinks.add(link);
    item.cdl = link;
  }
  insert recordLinks;
}
```

This code is likely not production ready, but hopefully illustrates how to deal with bulk Apex actions with callouts. Breaking up the code into smaller methods can make it easier to reason about what's going on in the code.

## Edit

Here's an entire, compilable source code. It needs an endpoint and a filename to use. This still probably isn't production ready, but I hope it'll get you closer to your goal.

```
public class ClientIDLookup {
    public class Request {
        @InvocableVariable (required=true) public String client_id;
        @InvocableVariable (required=true) public String linkedEntityId;
    }
    class Wrapper {
        Request req;
        ContentVersion cv;
        Id contentDocumentId;
        ContentDocumentLink cdl;
        Wrapper(Request request) {
            req = request;
        }
    }
    @InvocableMethod(label='Get Client Info' description='Gets the client info')
    public static void doGetClient(Request[] requests) {
        Wrapper[] wrappers = wrapRequests(requests);
        doCallouts(wrappers);
        createContentVersions(wrappers);
        getContentDocumentIds(wrappers);
        createDocumentLinks(wrappers);
    }
    static Wrapper[] wrapRequests(Request[] requests) {
        Wrapper[] results = new Wrapper[0];
        for(Request request: requests) {
            results.add(new Wrapper(Request));
        }
        return results;
    }
    static void doCallouts(Wrapper[] wrappers) {
        Http http = new http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        String endpoint;  // endpoint goes here
        req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Accept','application/pdf');
        for(Wrapper item: wrappers) {
            req.setBody(
                JSON.serialize(
                    new Map<String, Object> {
                        'client_id' => item.req.client_id
                    }
                )
            );
            String fileName;
            HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
            Map<String, Object> data = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
            Map<String, Object> pdfData = (Map<String, Object>)data.get('pdf');
            Blob fileData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode((String)pdfData.get('file'));
            item.cv = new ContentVersion(
                VersionData = fileData,
                Title = item.req.var_filename,
                PathOnClient = '/' + item.req.var_filename
            );
        }
    }
    static void createContentVersions(Wrapper[] wrappers) {
        ContentVersion[] versions = new ContentVersion[0];
        for(Wrapper item: wrappers) {
            versions.add(item.cv);
        }
        insert versions;
    }
    static void getContentDocumentIds(Wrapper[] wrappers) {
        Id[] versionIds = new Id[0];
        for(Wrapper item: wrappers) {
            versionIds.add(item.cv.Id);
        }
        Map<Id, ContentVersion> versionsById = new Map<Id, ContentVersion>([
            SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id = :versionIds
        ]);
        for(Wrapper item: wrappers) {
            item.contentDocumentId = versionsById.get(item.cv.Id).ContentDocumentId;
        }
    }
    static void createDocumentLinks(Wrapper[] wrappers) {
        ContentDocumentLink[] recordLinks = new ContentDocumentLink[0];
        for(Wrapper item: wrappers) {
            ContentDocumentLink link = new ContentDocumentLink(
                ContentDocumentId = item.contentDocumentId,
                linkedEntityId = item.req.linkedEntityId,
                ShareType = 'V'
            );
            recordLinks.add(link);
            item.cdl = link;
        }
        insert recordLinks;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are amazing ! Seriously, I can't believe the things I have seen you write !  I still need to comb through this for a couple more hours to truly grasp it all but I had to come on here and write some appreciation for now. Thank you so much ! I need to get back to this now. I apologize that I will have questions after properly going through it, but this is doing quite a lot. Thanks again !

Comment: @Zoom_v You're welcome! I tried to add clarity by breaking it up into functions, so hopefully it'll be pretty easy to get through.

Comment: again, thank you so much for taking the time to help with this. You have no idea just how much this is helping me. I apologize for my low level questions I'll ask here. I've been trying to use this but I'm having difficulty properly putting it into a class. I'm also getting error in some spots that are confusing. I can't tell if your different sections should be in one single class, or if you had intended for the Request and Wrapper class portion to be in a separate class which would be referenced. I see you put "code goes here" in your first portion but I'm confused. Thanks again.

Comment: @Zoom_v No worries. I stitched everything together for you. There were a couple of copy-paste errors and whatnot, so hopefully this will get you a lot closer. It should copy-and-paste compile directly into your org, you just need to update a couple of variables.

Comment: This is awesome sfdcfox. But I'm not sure I understand how you're using the InvocableVariables. Are you making them available by passing them into the Wrapper item ? If so, how are you doing that ? Is it just as easy as referencing them as item.req.client_id after you've created the item and once they've been declared as an InvocableVariable ? I feel like I'm missing something. Also, I'd like to have the Title of the ContentVersion be another InvocableVariable instead of the String filename. So how would I reference a third InvocableVariable there ? Thanks again.

Comment: @Zoom_v The flow sees the Request class, and checks the variables in there. This is how it knows to map the inputs in the Flow Builder. You actually haven't missed anything; item.req.client_Id would indeed map up to the flow's client_id parameter in the builder. To add the title, just add another InvocableVariable to Request, and you're all set. I'd recommend you just give it a try and see how it works. Start from the code I gave you, change some stuff, and see how Flow Builder changes.

Comment: I had intended for the Flow which creates the variables to be passed to the class to be record-triggered. It would have created those variables from a separate HTTP callout it conducted. But I'm just now finding out for the first time that a Flow with an HTTP callout can't be record triggered and must be on a schedule. What is the best way to handle this ? How would I have the record trigger the flow schedule to run in a minute ? I know it probably should just be done in Apex but I'd be struggling.

Comment: I need to do a bunch of other things in a Flow. So would like to initiate it all will a Flow. Would it be feasible to have a Flow initiated - and then run 2 separate Apex classes, each one of them running their own HTTP callout. The first would create the variable to be used as InvocableVariables here ?

Comment: @Zoom_v You can use a Record-Triggered flow. On the Start element, check the box that says "Include a Run Asynchronously path to access an external system after the original transaction for the triggering record is successfully committed", then you can add your Apex Action to the "Run Asynchronously" path.

Comment: Do you mean if I were to use 2 separate Apex classes with each doing their own callouts, or do you mean if I were to do one of the HTTP callouts in the Flow - and then passing the variables to an Apex which did a separate callout with the variables ?

Comment: I see what you mean. I've got it going with that path. Thanks again sfdcfox ! Just curious - what do you think I should expect as far as delay goes for this file-creating class to complete on that path ? Several seconds ? A minute ?

Comment: Looking now - I guess a minute is the fastest the asynch path can be run after the record has been updated. So, I guess we're looking at a one minute delay for the files being created.

Comment: @Zoom_v Depends on server resources. I've seen it run in fractions of a second, but your milage may vary.

Comment: Don't I need to reference the Named Credential that would be used here ? I don't see how that would come out properly without that Named Credential/External Services reference. Thank you.

Comment: Is it just a matter of including it in the endpoint with a 'callout:NamedCredential/' at the beginning of the endpoint ? Thank you.

Comment: @Zoom_v Correct, `String endpoint;` is the line where you'd add the endpoint, e.g. `String endpoint = 'callout:TheNamedCredential/path/file.ext';` or whatever you need.

Comment: I can't believe how easy Named Credential makes it ! (I sound like a commercial haha)

Comment: ok, I am sooo close on this ! I can successfully creating a file from the callout and placing it in the File of the proper Account record. But the file won't open properly, producing an error saying "Adobe Acrobat could not open the file because it is either not a supported file type or was damaged." I know we can't set FileType in ContentVersion and it is supposedly set by PathOnClient. I am setting PathOnClient as '/' + item.req.var_filename.I don't know if that is proper for setting the FileType.I have included the latest code in my original post.Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: @Zoom_v Open the file in a text editor. What does the file start off with?

Comment: I updated the original post to include what is shown when the file is opened in a text editor. Thank you.

Comment: @Zoom_v You're getting back JSON. I edited the final code block to demonstrate how to get the binary data you're looking for.

Comment: oh wow - I'm gonna put it in now. Did you just add those three lines after the HttpResponse line ?

Comment: @Zoom_v Yes, just added a little bit of JSON parsing and Base64 decoding, that's all that was missing.

Comment: Are you sure those three lines below the HTTPResponse line are all that was needed ? It doesn't seem to have changed anything. It's still giving the "not support file type" error and it looks exactly the same in the text editor.

Comment: @Zoom_v It would have failed to deploy, I somehow had `"` instead of `'` in the code. That said, yes, it should work.

Comment: Yha, I had changed it to single quote and it was deployed fine. Unfortunately I’m still getting the same results. The code is running without error. I’m gonna keep trying it with different requests to see if it might just be getting corrupt data in the response.. I can’t thank you enough sfdcfox. You’re incredible.